# Check if running during a rmarkdown::render

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would love to have a function that views a table in RStudio if I'm manually running code in an RMarkdown file, and uses `knitr::kable()` otherwise:

```r
ez_view <- function(df){
  if(`IS_RENDERING`){
    knitr::kable(df)
  } else {
    View(df)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `knitr::opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to')` to find out information on what `rmarkdown` is doing.  If you're not rendering, that will give `NULL`.  So this test should do what you want:

```
if (!is.null(knitr::opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to'))) {
  knitr::kable(df)
} else {
  View(df)
}
```